# PHP + MySQL WHERE EXISTS find_in_set returning all values

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table structure:

For `uc_users`:

```
id  |  following | Name
------------------------
1   |  2,3,      | Bill
2   |  1,3,      | Bob
3   |  1,        | Dan
```

I want to find out who user id 1 is following.

I have done the following:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM `uc_users` p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM `uc_users`
          WHERE `id` = 1 AND find_in_set(id, following) > 0
         )
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

But it's giving me all 3 users where it should only give users 2 and 3.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM `uc_users` p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM `uc_users`
          WHERE `id` = 1 AND find_in_set(p.id, following) > 0
         )
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

**Change:** `FIND_IN_SET(p.id,following) > 0`

Storing delimited list is too bad. Instead you should store record for each `<id,follower>` pair.

<kbd>[**Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)</kbd>

Comment: That did it. Thanks! I thought it was something simple I'm just new to this particular area. Thought I might have to take a downvote in order to ask.

Comment: Whoever downvoted your question **storing delimited list in column** might be the reason behind.@Ben

Comment: Yes I understand it's considered bad practise, however for my current situation it's fine. Sorry I normally do @1000111, it's annoying they make you wait before doing so. Thanks again.